# Floating point approximation to logarithms by powers and bit counting?

Tags: reference-request, computational-mathematics, computer-arithmetic

Earlier I both asked questions and found some interesting sources on the internet of how to do approximate division by combining and counting number of $0$s following most significant bit in denominator.

Example:
We represent a fraction $7/3$ as two ordered integers $(7,3)$.

We want to calculate a floating point approximation of it.

If we multiply both numerator and denominator by 11 we get the representation $(77,33)$ (for the same fraction).

Looking at the representation of 33 in binary: 100001, we can be tempted to replace the division by a bit-shift, if we pretend the binary expansion is 100000 ( pretending the second 1 and all that follows it is a 0 ).

The relative error will be about $1/32$ or in other words $3\%$. But all involved operations are super-fast to perform in electronics hardware (as long as we know a binary multiplicative "number-friend" of 3 is 11).

Now to my question, can we apply this same idea to approximate logarithms?

For example to calculate the 2-logarithm of $3$, we calculate $3\cdot 3$ is 9, bit expansion 1001, which we pretend to be 1000, giving an approximation of $\log_2(9) \approx 3$ or with log law: $2\log_2(3) \approx 3$ and therefore $\log_2{3} \approx \frac{3}{2} = 1.5$. The real value is $1.585...$, somewhat close(?)

Given that only multiplications and bit shifts are required and that we can without trouble throw away the least significant half of the product result, could this be a feasible approach for a floating point log approximator?

I suspect that it is reasonable to believe that this has already been tried, so any references you may have to such methods are heartily welcomed.

Comment: Discrete logs are always integers.   How can 1.585 be the “real value”?

Comment: Also, the 2-log of 3 in what modulus?  This really matters.

Comment: @Randall: Yep you are right. I did not even intend discrete logarithms but floating point approximations. Should have just written floating-point-approximation or something. I have changed the wording now.

Comment: Ah okay that’s a very different story/question.

Comment: Yes. Also the word matrix snuck into my question which should not even be there. Seems my stack has gotten a life of it's own.

Comment: If I understand the proposed algorithm correctly, this is essentially what is described in the [Wikipedia entry for the binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm), subsection "Iterative approximation".

Comment: @njuffa : I don't think they are the same. But they do make sure to utilize the same new hardware instruction *count leading zeros* or *find first set* which are new in SSE 4.2 (or something like that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the input. The algorithm I thought about was a bit more like this

1. take the number $a$ which we want to calc the log of. set $b=a$
2. loop until $b$ has $k$ most significant $1$ bits in a row:

   1. $b = a\times b$
   2. shift $b$ some bits so that we are sure to avoid overflow in subsequent multiplications, but count how large shift and store in exponent.
3. the position of the last $0$ before the first $1$ marks the exponent of $a^n$, where $n$ is the number of loop iterations
4. return $e/n$ where e is the sum of position in 3. and the accumulated exponent in the loop.

( Note that if we have floating point arithmetics we can skip keeping track of the exponent. Also the division by $n$ will be quickly implementable as a floating point multiplication by $\frac{1}{n}$ which we can tabulate if we would want )

We try on the number 666 with an implementation in the c language with gcc as compiler. We provide the value from c library logf function for reference.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}n&k&\text{output}&\text{logf}(666.0)\\2& 1&9.500000&9.379378\\5& 2&9.400001&9.379378\\13& 3&9.384616&9.379378\\29& 4&9.379311&9.379378\\\end{array}\right]$$

As we can see the number of iterations required to first find $k$ ones in a row grows a bit quickly. We would want to get an estimate faster, but as a first prototype it sure works.

Answer (score 1):

To use this approach you need a power of $3$, not a multiple, to be close to a power of $2$, and then you need to find it.  If you want $\log_2 5$ you could note that $125=5^3 \approx 2^7=128$ and say $3 \log_2 5 \approx 7, \log_2 5 \approx \frac 73 \approx 2.3333$ while the real value is about $2.322,$  so it is rather accurate.  It is not obvious to me how you find them.  Say you wanted $\log_2 19.$  How would you find a power of $19$ that is close to a power of $2$?  It turns out that $19^4=130321$ is quite close to $2^{17}=131072$, but I found it by computing $\log_2 19\approx 4.2479$ and rouding that to $\frac {17}4$

Comment: Yes it will be a power we will need for the logarithms. It is not particularly obvious to me either how to find these "power friends", but I am an engineer and only know the most rudimentary number theory.. Maybe someone else sees something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

The details of the proposed algorithm are not entirely clear to me, but it seems very similar to what is described in the Wikipedia [entry for binary logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_logarithm) in the section "Iterative approximation". Some references describing algorithms of this kind are:

J. C. Majithia and D. Levan, "A note on base-2 logarithm computations".
*Proceedings of the IEEE*, Vol. 61, No. 10, October 1973, pp. 1519-1520 (Reprinted in Earl E. Schwartzlander (ed.), *Computer Arithmetic* Volume 1, IEEE Computer Society Press, 1990, pp. 231-232)

Alan H. Karp, "Exponential and Logarithm by Sequential Squaring".
*IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 33, No. 5, May 1984, pp. 462-464

Hao-Yung Lo and Jau-Ling Chen, "Hardwired Generalized Algorithm for Generating the Logarithm Base-$k$ by Iteration".
*IEEE Transactions on Computers*, Vol. 36, No. 11, November 1987, pp. 1363-1367

Clay S. Turner, "A Fast Binary Logarithm Algorithm".
*IEEE Signal Processing Magazine*, Vol. 27, No. 5, September 2010, p. 124,140.

While the approach is certainly feasible, the preferred method for computing logarithms in floating-point arithmetic at this time is typically polynomial minimax approximation. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39822314/780717) for a worked example. For fixed-point computation on simple processors, the bit-wise computation by a pseudo-division process is often attractive; it goes back to the logarithm computations of H. Briggs in the early 17<sup>th</sup> century. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32163873/780717) for a worked example.